# Is this a bad practice to add die() at the end of "Views" in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, die

In order to make things right and prevent CodeIgniter from loading another views after a loaded view I needed to added `die()` at the end of views (footer). Is this a bad practice and Will this cause any problems?

The code is a little bit large to be posted here but I can say that there is an if statement which loads a view and by default the function loads another view. So when if statement gets passed, It loads the defined view and then the function loads the default view after it. I can use die() inside my controller but it gives me a blank page meaning that die() got executed before loading the view. and I can't neither use redirect().

Comment: It sounds like you're doing something wrong, only views you ask for will be loaded.

Comment: can you please post some code

Comment: It's a little bit large to be posted here but I can say that there is an `if statement` which loads a view and by default the function loads another view. So when `if statement` gets passed, it loads the defined view and then the function loads the default view after it. I can use `die()` in my controller but it gives me a blank page meaning that `die()` got executed before loading the view. and I can't neither use redirect().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bad practice. The end of the method at controller level is not the actual end of the execution of the code related to the request.
Codeignitor has a setup of loading a controller and then calling its method, and then executing other code after the method execution has finished.

Apart from the CodeIgnitor internal code, there are hooks

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html

if you have defined "post controller" hooks, which get executed after the controller method has finished,those will not be executed if you put `die` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bad practice, because after die no code will execute.
Suppose you have some code (Hooks) to be executed after loading of view it will not execute.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using die() mean there should be some reason for that. Can you please tell me why you want to use that at the end of views in CI?